# Can a wrongly crimped Ethernet Cable work, but not as intended?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

Recently I made an ethernet cable connection from my room to the room where the router is placed.

My expectations were to reduce lag in online games, as when I use wifi, the latency usually fluctuates a lot.

The problem is: The connection usually works fine, but I've noticed that I'm getting disconnected form the games more often than when I was using wifi.

Could that be due to a bad crimped ethernet connector? My thoughts are that Internet simply wouldn't work if it was not crimped correctly, but I suspect that I might have wrongly crimped one of the connectors.

My cable order is as follows:

```
Green White
Green
Orange White
Blue
Blue White
Orange
Brown White
Brown
```

The closest store for the connectors is a bit far away, and I don't want to crimp it again if that's not likely to be the problem. **Should I try to crimp my connectors again, or is that completely unrelated to my internet disconnections?**

Comment: It's rather a _length_ and associated lag issue.

Answer (score 1):

The actual pinout is supposed to be orange-white orange, green-whte blue, blue-whte gree, brown-white brown. https://www.trangosys.com/cat-5-ethernet-cable-standards-pin-out-assignments/ I'm assuming that you used a crimping tool. Also, make sure that your cable is not bent anywhere as that can cause issues. If you ever strip an ethernet cable, you will notice that the wires inside are not all he same as in the wires wrapped tightly or loosely. There is a reason for that. Also, you don't want to pass over any power supplies or ballasts as it can cause data transfer issues. There is another way that many people aren't aware of. A device that plugs into the power outlet and uses your existing electrical wiring to pass on data. We've been using this for over a year and a half and the connection is terrific. http://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/network-extenders/powerline  I don't know if this is useful to you or not. Hope so.

Comment: There are up to 4 'correct' ways to crimp a network cable. See http://blog.showmecables.com/rj45-pinout/ Most cables use the T568A method. Ensure both ends are crimped the same way for a straight through cable, which is what you want since you are plugging a computer in to your router. A properly crimped cat5e or better cable will out perform any current tech ethernet over power connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you made poor contact with one of the wires during crimping, it's possible that it could be intermittently disconnecting.  Theoretically, I suppose it's possible that variations in temperature could cause the wire to expand or contract just enough to make or break the connection.  If in doubt, just re-crimp it.

Comment: Keep in mind, some connectors are made to be used with braided and some with solid wires, make sure the connector type matches the wire type, or you'll never have a good connection.

Answer (score 1):

The "cable order" is important: Ethernet uses 4 pairs of wire to transmit data, and each pair uses [differential signaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling). In the ethernet cable, the pairs are wound around each other at a slightly different number of twists per length unit, and that reduces crossover talk between them.

If you don't match up the pairs correctly, like you did, you'll get crossover talk between the pairs, and they'll also be more susceptible to external electromagnetic noise. Add to that possibly bad crimping, and you have an unstable connection that *may* be the reason for the dropouts.

If in doubt, measure: Your OS should provide information about the number of hardware errors your ethernet hardware detected.

In any case, I recommend crimping again in any of the [correct orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8P8C_modular_connector#Pinout_3) (doesn't really matter which one you use, as long as the pairs match up correctly).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the wires in a wrong order, you're likely to just simply get no connection.  (Although, due to Auto-MDIX supporting crossover cable, there is at least one possibility of a flip in color order which may work perfectly fine with a bunch of equipment.)

If the wrongness is that the crimping job was poor, it is possible that breaks in communication (leading to apparent "disconnections") can occur.  This could be the issue.

Where I live, I've talked to computer people and found a bunch said they can crimp their own ends, with confidence in the results they create.  If you doubt the results of your abilities, you may want to ask around.